# Zener breakdown and Zener diodes

Tags: semiconductor-physics

While studying reverse biased P-N junctions, I came across the phenomenon of Zener breakdown and its implementation in Zener diodes. I have the following queries-

(A) What exactly is the reason behind Zener breakdown? As per my book, Zener breakdown occurs when the potential difference across the P-N junction is raised so much that the valence band electrons break free from their constituent bonds and jump into the conduction band. However, most sources I've come across on the internet so far mention quantum tunneling.
Which of these is true and how so?

(B) What would happen if an ideal Zener diode were to be put across a potential difference exceeding its breakdown voltage? In practicality, I suppose that the growth of the current with respect to the potential difference across the diode becomes steeper with increasing voltage but is finite for all finite voltages, as opposed to the idealized assumption of the growth of current rapidly to infinity within a short range of the breakdown voltage. Working under the ideal assumptions, how would a Zener diode behave when operated in a reverse biased configuration with a battery with a potential difference higher than the breakdown voltage?

Please keep your explanation of (A) simple if possible as I'm a high school student and have little background in quantum mechanics, except the basics.

Feel free to correct any of my points if you find them incorrect. Thank you

Comment: "What would happen if an ideal Zener diode were to be put across a potential difference exceeding its breakdown voltage?" You can only raise the reverse voltage any higher than the reverse breakdown voltage by supplying current. _Lots_ of current. You won't be able to raise the voltage by more than a little bit before you've [let the magic smoke out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke).